# Оптимизация через многопоточность Java

Tags: java

Есть программа, которая генерирует автомобильные номера. Нужно было оптимизировать я запустил поток на каждый регион. В итоге создается 99 текстовых файлов. Сейчас нужно сделать 4 файла. Не могу придумать, как сделать этот шаг между записями и созданием потоков. Ниже код.

```java
             import java.io.PrintWriter;
             import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Loader {
    public static PrintWriter writer;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        writer = new PrintWriter("res/numbers.txt");
        final char letters[] = {'У', 'К', 'Е', 'Н', 'Х', 'В', 'А', 'Р', 'О', 'С', 'М', 'Т'};

        for (int i = 0; i < Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(); i++) {
                service.submit(new ThreadLoader(i));
        }
        service.shutdown();

        while (!service.isTerminated()) {
        }

        System.out.println("Время выполнения несколькими потоками - " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms");

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();


        for (int regionCode = 1; regionCode < 100; regionCode++) {
            for (int number = 1; number < 1000; number++) {
                for (char firstLetter : letters) {
                    for (char secondLetter : letters) {
                        for (char thirdLetter : letters) {
                            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                            builder.append(firstLetter);
                            builder.append(padNumber(number, 3));
                            builder.append(secondLetter);
                            builder.append(thirdLetter);
                            builder.append(padNumber(regionCode, 2));
                            builder.append("\n");
                            writer.write(builder.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        System.out.println("Время выполнения одним потоком - " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms");
    }

    private static StringBuilder padNumber(int number, int numberLength)
    {
        String numberStr = Integer.toString(number);
        int padSize = numberLength - numberStr.length();
        StringBuilder padNumbers = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < padSize; i++) {
            padNumbers.append("0");
        }
        padNumbers.append(numberStr);
        return padNumbers;
    }
}
```

И с ранбл

```java
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class ThreadLoader implements Runnable {

    public PrintWriter writer;
    public StringBuilder builder;
    public int regionCode;

    final char letters[] = {'У', 'К', 'Е', 'Н', 'Х', 'В', 'А', 'Р', 'О', 'С', 'М', 'Т'};

    public ThreadLoader(int i) throws FileNotFoundException {
        writer = new PrintWriter("res/numbers" + i + ".txt");
        builder = new StringBuilder();
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int regionCode = 1; regionCode < 100; regionCode++) {
            for (int number = 1; number < 1000; number++) {
                for (char firstLetter : letters) {
                    for (char secondLetter : letters) {
                        for (char thirdLetter : letters) {
                            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                            builder.append(firstLetter);
                            builder.append(padNumber(number, 3));
                            builder.append(secondLetter);
                            builder.append(thirdLetter);
                            builder.append(padNumber(regionCode, 2));
                            builder.append("\n");
                            writer.write(builder.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }


    private static StringBuilder padNumber(int number, int numberLength) {
        String numberStr = Integer.toString(number);
        int padSize = numberLength - numberStr.length();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < padSize; i++) {
            builder.append("0");
        }
        builder.append(numberStr);
        return builder;
    }
}
```

Comment: Создадите вы 172_800_000 номеров и что?

Comment: Я уже не говорю о том что их можно генерировать со скоростью которая ограничена только скоростью вашего диска. То есть параллелить нет смысла.

Comment: А какой принцип разбиения на файлы?

Answer (score 1):

На моей машине ваш однопоточный код работает 22 секунды. Многопоточный (восемь потоков) 80 секунд. Потому что он создаёт восемь копий одного и того же файла.

Если оптимизировать создание номера, можно уложится в десять секунд. Делать параллельную обработку не вижу смысла:

```
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class LicensePlates {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(args[0])) {

            final char digits[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
            final char letters[] = {'У', 'К', 'Е', 'Н', 'Х', 'В', 'А', 'Р', 'О', 'С', 'М', 'Т'};

            //               0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
            char[] plate = {'A', '1', '2', '3', 'B', 'C', '4', '5', '\n'};

            for (int rc = 1; rc < 100; ++rc) {
                plate[7] = digits[rc % 10];
                plate[6] = digits[rc / 10];
                for (int n = 1; n < 1000; ++n) {
                    plate[3] = digits[n % 10];
                    int t = n / 10;
                    plate[2] = digits[t % 10];
                    plate[1] = digits[t / 10];
                    for (char l1 : letters) {
                        plate[0] = l1;
                        for (char l2 : letters) {
                            plate[4] = l2;
                            for (char l3 : letters) {
                                plate[5] = l3;
                                writer.write(plate);    
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ javac LicensePlates.java 
>
> $ time java LicensePlates out
>
> real  0m9.748s
> user  0m8.692s
> sys   0m1.256s
>
> $ time wc out
>  170900928  170900928 2050811136 out
>
> real  0m32.508s
> user  0m32.212s
> sys   0m0.284s
> ```

Обратите внимание что файл строится 10 секунд, а `wc` считает в нем строки, слова и символы 33 секунды.

**P.S.** Эту версию можно ещё разогнать избавившись от перевода массива символов в байты (это делается внутри `writer.write`).

**P.P.S.** Удивительно что эта же программа с печатью в `System.out.print` работает в 25 раз медленнее. Никогда такой разницы не видел. В `C` и `Python` обычно нет разницы куда слать данные. А тут такое. Чтобы это значило?